# Extra empty table headers appear with every filled table

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

In my report viewer i have a list grouped by office name and within the list i have two other lists one groups on Case Activity and the other groups on NonCase Activity. for both the inner lists i have a groupon expression that filters what type of data is shown in each.

Here is my Group on expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!Cases.Value Is Nothing, Fields!OfficeName.Value, " ")
```

This expression filters all the items where the case value is 0 into a table and if cases do exist then show nothing. I believe because of " " that it is showing the headers for the empty table. How can i change the expression so that not only the table is empty but also not show the headers of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually realized that instead of filtering the table - i applied the same filter expression to my list and it removed empty table with headers.